# Aicrack-ng problem.... monior mode enabled on wlan0mon but airodump causes system log out

Tags: aircrack-ng, iwlwifi

Ubuntu 14.04 LTS

So the device goes into monitor mode on `wlan0mon` but wifi is disconnnected (strange) when I run `airodump-ng wlan0mon` it starts the scan then runs for a minute or 2 with no results (I am standing right next to my Wifi router) then the system logs me out??? why? I am once again "puzzled"...

Help me please! :(

```
Aircrack-ng 1.2 rc1 r2459 - (C) 2006-2014 Thomas d'Otreppe
```

`airmon-ng start wlan0`

```
Found 5 processes that could cause trouble.
If airodump-ng, aireplay-ng or airtun-ng stops working after
a short period of time, you may want to kill (some of) them!

  PID Name
  591 avahi-daemon
  594 avahi-daemon
 1089 NetworkManager
 1166 wpa_supplicant
 1882 dhclient

PHY Interface   Driver      Chipset

phy0    wlan0       iwlwifi     Intel Corporation Wireless 7260 (rev 73)

        (mac80211 monitor mode vif enabled for [phy0]wlan0 on [phy0]wlan0mon)
        (mac80211 station mode vif disabled for [phy0]wlan0)
```

Answer (score 0):

airmon-ng check kill .

In Aircrack-ng v1.2 RC2

Airmon-zc looks like will replace airmon-ng.